# How to simplify the output to only one value per duplicate

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I found this code on Stack Overflow and I modified it a little (I added more values to the arrays). I was wondering how I could get the result to only show the matching values once.

Here's the code below:

```js
var arrays = [
['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza',],
['taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza',],
['banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple',]
];
var result = arrays.shift().filter(function(v) {
return arrays.every(function(a) {
       return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
     });
});

document.write('<pre>' +
  JSON.stringify(result,null,4)
+ '</pre>');
```

(Sorry if I got the tags wrong, I think this is javascript but there are so many different libraries in javascript it's hadr to tell.).

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Remove duplicates per array? Or between the 3 arrays?

Comment: Seconding baao -- an example of what the expected output should look like would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to have every item only once as a result, the easiest thing to do is to use a Set - it's unique by definition.

```js
var arrays = [
['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza',],
['taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza',],
['banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple',]
];

let result = [...new Set(arrays.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b), []))];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the intersection of `m` arrays and also removing the duplicates can be done in O(n) time by using a hash where `n` is the total number of elements in the arrays;

```js
function arrayIntersect(a){
  var hash = {};
  a.forEach((e,i) => e.forEach(function(s){
                                 var h = hash[s];
                                 h ? h[h.length-1] !== i && h.push(i)
                                   : hash[s] = [i];
                               }));
  return Object.keys(hash)
               .filter(f => hash[f].length === a.length);
}

var arrays = [['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza','apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'fish', 'pancake', 'taco', 'pizza'],
              ['taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza','taco', 'fish', 'apple', 'pizza'],
              ['banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple','banana', 'pizza', 'fish', 'apple']
             ];

console.log(arrayIntersect(arrays));
```

In this particular case the `hash` object would look like

```
{   apple: [0, 1, 2],
   orange: [0],
   banana: [0, 2],
     pear: [0],
     fish: [0, 1, 2],
  pancake: [0],
     taco: [0, 1],
    pizza: [0, 1, 2]}
```

at the end. We are interested only in the properties with values having a length same as the provided number of arrays (`a.length`).